# Undoing a question deletion that had a deleted answer brought the answer back?

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I asked a question back in December, and while going through my questions today I saw that it had no answers, so I decided to delete it, but I almost immediately changed my mind, so I reversed it.

An answer that was previously deleted is now showing up again. Is this how it's suppose to work?

Edit: I might be mistaken on what happened, I just tried it here and it just added a vote for deletion on my answer. Shouldn't my answer remain deleted?

Comment: Now that's a Necromancer!

Comment: A fix for this will be pushed in tonight's build.

Answer (score 10):

It was my answer that came back, I can no longer delete it. [Here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929150/can-someone-explain-to-me-what-this-code-is-checking/1930039#1930039).

I see a Delete(1) tag underneath and when I click that it shows a "You already voted to delete..." message.

Comment: Maybe you already know, but if you really want it gone you can flag it

Comment: @Koper, Yes, I'm not too concerned about this answer. But I would like this bug fixed.