# Please don't undelete the answer if there is close vote on that answer upon undeletion of question

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, undelete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undoing a question deletion that had a deleted answer brought the answer back?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40066/undoing-a-question-deletion-that-had-a-deleted-answer-brought-the-answer-back)

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418914/how-to-construct-a-string-based-on-regex-and-related-parameters-in-php) the answers were deleted because the question changed - [1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2418925/revisions) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2418935/revisions)

But, the question is [deleted and then undeleted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2418914/revisions) for a moment by the OP (I'm not sure it's intentional or not).

After that, we cannot delete our answers anymore, and it's showing "delete  (1)"

[shot of delete(1) http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/4272/delete1.jpg](http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/4272/delete1.jpg)

When question is undeleted, I understand, answers should be undeleted too.

But in this case, there is a vote to delete, which is known and held by system.

When the question is undeleted, and when undeleting answers, can the system skip the answers if there is delete vote?

Comment: voting to close it, but I wish this to be solved.