# Undeleting a question undeletes deleted answers and prevents authors from re-deleting them!

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, vote-to-delete, undelete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undoing a question deletion that had a deleted answer brought the answer back?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40066/undoing-a-question-deletion-that-had-a-deleted-answer-brought-the-answer-back)

[See here for example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51192/why-was-the-question-owner-able-to-delete-their-own-question). ([tell-tale revision list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/51200/revisions))

If I post an answer to a question and then delete it, and the OP then deletes and undeletes the question itself, my answer is undeleted with it. This is a bug - normally, users aren't able to undelete other users' answers.

Worse yet, the system considers my deletion to have used up my vote, and will no longer allow me to delete the erroneously-deleted answer. This second bug makes the first harder to work around...

(could have sworn this had been reported previously, but can't find it now!)

Comment: Oh, it's definitely been reported before. I'll see if I have better luck in finding it. - nevermind, S.Mark got it

Comment: here it is - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40066/undoing-a-question-deletion-that-had-a-deleted-answer-brought-the-answer-back

Comment: Excellent, thanks @S.Mark! Argh, status-by-design, *not* excellent. Voting to close as a dup so I can find this again next time...