# Spam-flagged post not deleted

Tags: bug, flags, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undoing a question deletion that had a deleted answer brought the answer back?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40066/undoing-a-question-deletion-that-had-a-deleted-answer-brought-the-answer-back)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538156/file-i-o-in-every-programming-language/3540837#3540837) was flagged as spam 6 times, and in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3540837/revisions) it claims to have been locked and deleted by Community, but the post was only locked. It still shows on the question page as non-deleted, and it still appears on the spam flag list (with 6 flags)

---

**Edit**: It looks like Bill undeleting the question undeleted all the answers, including the Community-deleted one, so that's the real bug. I'm not sure if this would also undelete self-deleted posts, or if 10k users voting to undelete would cause this (versus just being caused by mod actions), but either of those being true would make this somewhat more serious

Comment: Dupe of [Community Wiki questions and the subjective close](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61906/community-wiki-questions-and-the-subjective-close)? BTW, in the accepted answer on that question, the mod who deleted the post explained why he [undeleted it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61906/#61912).

Comment: @Dori This is definitely not a dupe of that question, but Bill undeleting that question does explain the problem; I revised the question